# How to disable direct media file access in Nginx or Ubuntu for non-logged-in users?

Tags: apache, nginx, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to disable direct URL access (for images, PDF) to my WordPress websites for non-logged-in users, I have created one '`.htaccess` file' under - `wp-content/uploads/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

this worked in Apache (localhost), but when I am trying to upload the same in Nginx (siteground), it's not working.

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache configuration file.  Nginx doesn't use them.  You'll need to find a different solution.  Is this a VPS?  Can you edit the Nginx configuration files?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, let me find another method

Comment: As long as you're using WordPress, you might as well use a plugin for this. There are several that are well maintained that will accomplish this for you. Otherwise, you're going to have to write a script to check if a user is logged in (`is_user_logged_in()` will be helpful) and proxy requests to the filetypes you're interested in restricting.

Comment: @MikeCiffone yes, few free plugins are there which didn't work for nginx, paid plugins are there with budget of more then 500 $, trying to fix this from my side, thanks :)

Comment: @MikeCiffone yes, 'is_user_logged_in()' is protecting the page and that's what I am doing, but direct url of media file is accessible